# pdf.js not loading pdf file

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I'm very new to pdf.js and am probably making some basic mistake. I'm trying to just copy the "Hello World with document load error handling" example provided here:

https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/

I just copy and pasted the code across to new html, css and js files but didn't work. I tried changing the url in pdfjsLib.getDocument(url) to a local file directory on my computer i.e. ./pdf/test.pdf but didn't work. I tried changing the

```
<script src="//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@2.2.228/build/pdf.min.js"></script>
```

but that didn't work either.

My console log states two things:

1) Loading failed for the  with source “file:///pdf.js/build/pdf.js”

2) TypeError: pdfjsLib is undefined

I understand I am a beginner here but would it be too much to ask the guys who put so much effort into creating it to write a few lines about how to use it for beginners like me? Anyways, if someone can help solve my what I'm sure is a very basic question, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Most of these problems are caused by the fact that you are running your test by opening an html file, thus the browser use the `file://` instead of `http://` or `https://`.

A quick "hack" to fix the problem in you situation is to insert the `<base href="https://mozilla.github.io">` (HTML base tag) inside the `head` of your test html file (I used the given example as it is, with no changes inside a blank html document) so that you fool the browser and make it search on the Github for the files.

The "correct" way to test such codes and libraries is to install a local web-server and serve the files from there (usually as `http://localhost`).

An example of the test I created:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Testing pdf.js">
        <meta name="author" content="GramThanos">

        <!-- hack code -->
        <base href="https://mozilla.github.io">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>

        <h1>PDF.js 'Hello, world!' example</h1>

        <canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            // If absolute URL from the remote server is provided, configure the CORS
            // header on that server.
            var url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ba2edeae/examples/learning/helloworld.pdf';

            // Loaded via <script> tag, create shortcut to access PDF.js exports.
            var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];

            // The workerSrc property shall be specified.
            pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';

            // Asynchronous download of PDF
            var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(url);
            loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
              console.log('PDF loaded');

              // Fetch the first page
              var pageNumber = 1;
              pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
                console.log('Page loaded');

                var scale = 1.5;
                var viewport = page.getViewport({scale: scale});

                // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
                var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                canvas.height = viewport.height;
                canvas.width = viewport.width;

                // Render PDF page into canvas context
                var renderContext = {
                  canvasContext: context,
                  viewport: viewport
                };
                var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
                renderTask.promise.then(function () {
                  console.log('Page rendered');
                });
              });
            }, function (reason) {
              // PDF loading error
              console.error(reason);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So strange. I copied and pasted your example and it worked. But when I go back to my files and add the <base href="https://mozilla.github.io"> in the header it didn't work. I compared my files to your example. The only difference is that you put the javascript in script tags in your html. I wrote the javascript in my js file. So I moved what I had in my js file into my html file and put it in script tags and now it works. I don't know why I can't just have it in my js file.

Comment: I'm looking into creating a local server as I will need to do this eventually as I move to the server-side development. I've never done it before or server-side stuff before so pretty daunting. But yes I'm just starting to learn about it now

Comment: Just to be sure in case you missed it, `<base href="mozilla.github.io">` is not the same as `<base href="https://mozilla.github.io">`. Since your URL `mozilla.github.io` has no protocol in frond of it, it is a relative path, thus it is translated as `file:///<path-to-html-file>/mozilla.github.io`.

Comment: Oh!! I will try this out when I get back on my laptop! Thanks